# Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (IteratorGetNext:1) to a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, graph, networkx

I was trying to implement a metric namely APLS(Avg. Path Length Similarity) metric.I needed to perform some operations upon the groundtruth and the predicted image and generate a graph before calculating the APLS. Upon passing the groundtruth and predicted image to the graph generating function, I get this error:

`NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (IteratorGetNext:1) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.` 
Could someone guide me a resolution and or an alternate code for my graph generating function which presently is:

```
def ImageToGraph(imageArray):
    image = np.array(imageArray).astype(bool)
    skeleton = skeletonize(image)
    ske = skeleton.astype(np.uint8)
    return sknw.build_sknw(ske)
```

The error occurs in line 1 of the function which says a symbolic tensor could not be converted to a numpy array.

I tried using the Keras backend methods but there were issues when i pass those tensors to the skeleton which says that a the skeleton function accepts a 2D image but i provided 5 dimensions(batch size is 5) but my groundtruth was a 2D image. Below is the model i am trying to train.

```
model = sm.Unet(
    'efficientnetb0', 
    classes=1,                   
    input_shape=(256, 256, 5),
    encoder_weights=None,       
    activation='sigmoid'
)
model.compile(optimizer=Nadam(lr=0.0002), loss=bce_dice_apls_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])
```

Answer (score 0):

TF does not work with numpy arrays for graph building. You need to cast your stuff from numpy to tensors before using them. Instead of:

```
image = np.array(imageArray).astype(bool)
```

you could try

```
image = tf.constant(imageArray, dtype=tf.bool)
```

Note that all operations once in graph need to use tf compatible functions. If you want to use numpy you have to wrap the function in a tf.numpy_function call.

Comment: Thank you ma'am. I faced new errors: "    TypeError: Expected bool, got <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None, None, None) dtype=float32> of type 'Tensor' instead.". Could you please suggest me some resources from where i can read about them myself.

Comment: Dont have any resources but read the error. At some point you are trying to call some sort of operation on the tensor that treats it as a boolean even though it is a tensor of type float.